# MongoDB query using $where and length

Tags: mongodb

With the following data structure below, I would like to fetch all objects where the length of the value of `'location.country'` is equal to 2:

DataStructure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("252532"),
    "date" : ISODate("2015-03-27T20:32:56.578Z"),
    "location" : {
        "country" : "BR",
        "coordinate" : [
            -8.95,
            -35.65
        ]
    },
    "type": 2
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("252525"),
    "date" : ISODate("2015-03-28T01:33:30.361Z"),
    "location" : {
        "country" : "Brazil",
        "coordinate" : [
            -15.816699981689453,
            -48.11669921875
        ]
    },
    "type": 2
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("24242"),
    "date" : ISODate("2015-03-28T01:33:30.471Z"),
    "type":1

}, ....
```

I have tried the following query but I get an error which I don't understand.

```
db.collection.find({$where: "this.location.country.length == 2"});

Error: error: {
    "$err" : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'country' of undefined\n    at _funcs1 (_funcs1:1:43) near 'length == 2' ",
    "code" : 16722}
```

Could anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First check if location exist:

```
db.collection.find({location: {$type: 3}, $where: "this.location.country.length == 2"});
```

Comment: I was pretty sure it had something to do with that but couldn't get the syntax right. Thanks

Comment: @Ryan - Thanks. Consider using additional field with county name length for better performance.